# Which battery will be good for gas/water metering - lithium thionyl chloride or lithium manganese dioxide?

Tags: batteries, lithium

We are working on gas/water meters.

We are currently using lithium thionyl chloride batteries for our device. After reading some technical documents we found that the lithium manganese dioxide batteries perform much better than lithium thionyl chloride batteries. They are also cost effective as well as good life cycle. They mentioned that with LiMNO2 batteries,  the device can operate for at least 10yrs.

Our device operates at:

- Vin=2.5V
- I out(minimum)=200uA
- I out(maximum)=100mA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was involved in the design of a gas-meter and, it used a 10 year lifetime battery using Lithium Thionyl Chloride technology. It was a D type size battery. Can't give specific details as IP is involved.

> *they mentioned that By using LiMNO2 the device can operate for at
> least 10yrs.*

Lithium Thionyl Chloride can achieve 10 years and, at quite low temperatures too so, I think you need to do some more research here.

> *after reading Technical Documents we come to know that the lithium
> manganese dioxide performs much better than lithium thionyl chloride
> Batteries*

Maybe, but the devil's in the detail and some technical documents masquerade as being technical when really they are written by marketing departments.

Comment: How can we identify the battery whether it is D type or other type, I checked the battery datasheet and not nothing about the size (except measurements of it).

Comment: I know nothing about what data sheet you checked do I?

Comment: @vinayakpotadar D is a [formerly common size of battery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_battery). I believe it went by the name of "LR20" (at least the alkaline ones) in many countries. Andy is just referring to the dimensions of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

How about this: it depends. I work for a battery company and I model both types of cells. Temperature, time, passivation, pulse current, how often current is drawn, etc., all come into play. Best to let a manufacturer work with your specific application and help you decide.